# How about adding "..\" to the inclusion path to distinguish between the root path and the current path?

Tags: c++, header, include

I've added a $(ProjectDir) path to the INCLUDE environment variable to include files from project root directory. But I often get confused whether the header I included is based on the current folder or Project Directory. For example,

```
//Current Path
#include "EditorResource.h"

//From root Path
#include "Manager/TimeManager.h"
#include "Manager/ThreadPoolManager.h"
#include "Manager/PathManager.h"
```

Even if there is no comment in the code above, I would like to distinguish whether the header I included is based on the project root directory or the current directory.

So instead of adding `$(ProjectDir)` in INCLUDE path, I want to add a `$(ProjectDir)..\` variable and change it to the same way as the code below,

```
//Current Path
#include "EditorResource.h"

//From root Path
#include "Engine/Manager/TimeManager.h"
#include "Engine/Manager/ThreadPoolManager.h"
#include "Engine/Manager/PathManager.h"
```

Will there no problem?

...Or is it unnecessary to distinguish this?

Comment: Do yourself a favor and always use the full relative path.